# Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem and algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am a first year graduate student and want to study algebraic geometry and eventually write my PhD thesis in algebraic geometry. As someone who wants to be an algebraic geometer, why should I be interested in Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem? How are Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem and algebraic geometry related?

Comment: The AS index theorem is an application of topological methods to algebraic geometry. That could be enough of a reason for wishing to study it...

Comment: One relation is that it is a generalisation of the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem.

Comment: The algebraic geometry counterpart of the Atiyah-Singer theorem is the Hirzebruch- (or Grothendieck-) Riemann-Roch theorem. If you want to study algebraic geometry, you definitely must study these. You will certainly not need AS in the first years when you learn algebraic geometry. And if you need it later (I doubt it, but who knows?), you'll learn it at that moment.

Comment: There are lots of different flavours of algebraic geometry. But I would argue you don't need the AS index theorem in general; more important is Riemann-Roch and its generalisations as found in e.g. Hartshorne.

Comment: Have a look  at Hirzebruch's classic "Topological methods in algebraic topology"